# Pegasus R6 - No Physical drive in the Enclosure

Tags: macos, raid-5

I have a Pegasus R6 (an external thunderbolt connected RAID array).

I am trying reactivate 2 "dead" drives with the help of a shell and the command  PromiseUtil.

`Phydrv -a list` gives the message: `No physical drive in the enclosure.`

`Enclosure -a list` result in `id#1 - Pegasus-R6`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does `phydrv -a online -p 1` (repeat for all 6 drives) work?  (See [http://superuser.com/questions/544597/promise-pegasus-report-dead-after-power-failure](http://superuser.com/questions/544597/promise-pegasus-report-dead-after-power-failure)).

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the terminal commands. Did you run this exact command? Also which drives are failing? Example 1 or 3 or 5 or 6. When using the command listed below the number reflects the physical bay of the enclosure.

```
phydrv -a online -p 1
```

You probably know this but I thought this would be helpful.